# PHP Redirect stopped working?

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

I have wrote a script to update a MySql DB from a form.

After the DB has been updated I want the page to auto redirect to another page.

This has been working fine however since switching hosting provider non of my sites re-directs work.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "XXX";
$password = "XXX";
$dbname = "XXX";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

 $id= $_POST[id];
 $dob=$_POST[dob];

$sql=("update users set dob='$dob' where id='$id'")or die('Error 23 ' . mysql_error());

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Updated successfully<br /><br />";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
?>
<?php
header("location:index.php?action=updated");  ?>
```

When I run the code the DB updates but the page just displays `Updated successfully`?

Comment: u can move the redirect code, i:e the header function to if part after displaying the message updated successfully

Comment: is there any .htaccess file in your domain root folder? if so then remove it and then see you header is working or not?

Comment: Moving the code hasn't made a difference.

Comment: @PayerAhammed - Nope .htaccess file

Comment: try header with absolute path like `header('Location: http://www.example.com/index.php?action=updated');`

Comment: @PayerAhammed - Nope still wont redirect?

Comment: manually type your url in browser address bar like `http://www.example.com/index.php?action=updated` then see it work or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't echo anything and try to redirect afterwards. Instead simply redirect without any echoing.

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header("location:index.php?action=updated");
    exit;
} else
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
```

Comment: It still isn't redirecting?

Answer (score 2):

try using javascript to redirect like below:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<script>
          alert('Updated successfully');
          window.location.href = 'index.php?action=updated';
         </script>";
}
```

Comment: Perfect, it redirects. Any idea why I cant use PHP to do this anymore?

Comment: if u use header function it will directly redirect you without giving the message that it is updated successfully.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<?php 
ob_start();
header('Location: http://www.example.com/index.php?action=updated', true); 
?>
```

Comment: Nope does not re-direct?

Comment: use `<?php ob_start(); ?>` this before header